# Executando processos em segundo plano - Acessando mesmo script duas vezes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, background-services

Possuo um script em PHP que tem como objetivo a integração com um sistema de terceiros.

Basicamente, o meu script envia arquivos de imagem e texto para o ftp do cliente.

Para garantir o processamento por um longo tempo, eu uso a seguinte instrução:

```
ignore_user_abort( true ); // Não interrompe o script em caso de perda de conexão
set_time_limit( 21600 ); // Time out após 6h
```

Também, para impedir duplo processamento, é criado no início um arquivo que, ao final do script, é apagado.

De maneira que, se o arquivo existe, é porque o processo está em execução.

O script funciona lindamente.

O problema está no fato de que este script é chamado via AJAX pelo meu sistema (de forma assíncrona), sendo então rodado em segundo plano. Mas daí, uma vez iniciado o processo, não consigo fazer mais nada no sistema enquanto o mesmo não termina, a não ser que eu abra em outro navegador ou usando outro protocolo (um com www e outro sem).

Isso é limitação do navegador, ou é algo que possa ser configurado no servidor/php?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

**Obs.**: Há vários processos executados em segundo plano no sistema, porém, este é o único que trava os demais processamentos.

Comment: Está a fazer ajax sincrono?

Comment: @Sergio O acesso é assincrono naturalmente. Na verdade o sistema faz vários processos em segundo plano... este é o únicco que bloqueia outros processamentos.

Comment: @Szag-Ot, ok, pode explicar melhor "não consigo fazer mais nada no sistema enquanto o mesmo não termina"? Quem está a bloquear outros processamentos?

Comment: @Sergio, qualquer processo/link/página do mesmo domínio que se tente acessar, não é aberto até que o processo supracitado tenha terminado. O navegador fica esperando. E, no caso de outros processos em segundo plano, não são executados até o término deste.

Comment: socket ocupado, quando liberar um vc usa, ou alias, que é o caso quando você usa o www ou 127.0.0.1 por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok pessoal, agradeço o tempo que vocês dispensaram me ajudando (em especial o @Sergio), porém encontrei a solução.

O problema está em um erro simples. Já o havia cometido antes, mas fazia tempo... acabei por me lembrar e realmente constatei ser o seguinte:

Eu abro uma sessão no início do processo (com `session_start()`, naturalmente) mas não a fecho em nenhum momento (com `session_write_close()`).

Não se trata de encerrar nem de destruir a sessão. É apenas uma questão de se informar para o script que você não precisa mais dela depois de determinado ponto.

Uma vez colocado `session_write_close()` logo após a linha a fazer uso da sessão pela última vez, o problema não ocorre mais.

Mais uma vez obrigado!