# Configuração de Servidor WHM/Apache + jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, linux, whm

Recentemente comecei a ter o seguinte problema nos domínios do meu servidor com WHM:

Ao executar uma chamada AJAX assincrona em segundo plano, não consigo prosseguir, isto é, não consigo acessar mais nada no mesmo domínio pelo mesmo terminal que executou a chamada enquanto o processo não conclui.

Isso passa a impressão de lentidão no sistema, quando na verdade é apenas o problema de o dominio ficar "bloqueado" enquanto há um processo em segundo plano (mesmo se abrir outra aba do navegador)

Se acessar de outro terminal - ainda que esteja na mesma rede - acessa normalmente.

Isso é algo que acontece em testes locais (usando o PHP Built in) pq o BuiltIn não permite mais de uma conexão simultanea.

Mas isso não deve ocorrer no servidor.

Como antes não era assim, acredito que isso se deva a alguma alteração nas configurações do servidor.

Porém como não faço idéia do que possa ser, não consigo localizar nada nas configurações que possa ocasionar esse comportamento.

**Obs:** O sistema é feito em PHP 7. O servidor usa apache 2.4 + CloudLinux para evitar abuso de recursos por parte de um único domínio

Comment: Você já entrou em contato com suporte do seu servidor? Isso ocorre em qualquer lugar no sistema? Deu uma olhada no Web Console do navegador pra ver se mostra algum erro?

Comment: @WendelRodrigues a resposta é a mesma para as 3 perguntas: Sim. No caso da segunda pergunta, passou a acontecer em todo o sistema, mas só é sentido quando o processo é mais demorado.

Comment: Mas e ai, o suporte disse nada? Viu diferente no console? Tem como postar alguma coisa pra gente ver?

Comment: Talvez esse link possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56304/servidor-apache-php-n%C3%A3o-responde-enquanto-est%C3%A1-fazendo-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-soap. Parece ser um problema semelhante ao que você descreveu, por isso quando acessa de outro terminal ele funciona, porque o bloqueio é na sua sessão.

Comment: Pensei nisso tb, mas os arquivos q usam sessão já fecham com session_write_close(), sendo q a maioria não usa sessão

Comment: Cara, o servidor deve estar bloqueando as requisições então. Já verificou isso com eles? Seu servidor tem stats? Vê quais páginas tem mais acessos e se são as que ocasionam os problemas.

Comment: As requisições não estão sendo bloqueadas. Elas executam. Só que uma de cada vez.

Comment: @WendelRodrigues muito obrigado pela atenção e ajuda até o momento. Descobri qual foi a alteração do servidor que estava travando: O CORS. Corrigido e funcionando. Assim que tiver um tempo, vou postar a resposta em detalhes. Independenten disso porem, poderia por gentileza detalhar como resposta o que vc colocou a respeito do session_write_close()? Embora não era isso neste caso, mas daí te passo a recompensa pela ajuda prestada

Comment: Hum, interessante. Vou dar uma lida sobre isso. Posta sim depois. ;) Vlws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problema solucionado**

Há um tempo, tive um problema semelhante, relatado aqui: [Executando processos em segundo plano - Acessando mesmo script duas vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29207/executando-processos-em-segundo-plano-acessando-mesmo-script-duas-vezes)

Contudo, desta vez o motivo foi outro: a última atualização de nosso servidor com WHM modificou uma diretiva que impedia o Cross-Domain. E como muitos dos nossos processos usam CORS, estava havendo um bloqueio.

Para corrigir, ao invés de mudarmos no servidor para que funcionasse, fizemos uso da dica neste outro link: [Requisição Ajax cross-domain com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)

Espero que as dicas nestes 2 links possa ser de ajuda a outros que passem por problemas similares.

Obrigado em especial ao @WendelRodrigues pela ajuda prestada!

Answer (score 0):

Talvez esse link possa te ajudar: [Servidor Apache/PHP não responde enquanto está fazendo uma requisição SOAP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56304/servidor-apache-php-n%C3%A3o-responde-enquanto-est%C3%A1-fazendo-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-soap) Parece ser um problema semelhante ao que você descreveu, por isso quando acessa de outro terminal ele funciona, porque o bloqueio pode ser na sua sessão.